# Where can I find a complete table of sprocket and with chain/hub/sprocket spacer width combinations?

Tags: chain

For example:

```
number of speeds  chain width  hub width  spacer width
1                 
5
6
7
8 
9
10
11
```

There are various tables (for example on https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-spacing.html) but I haven't found one with all the data, showing what combinations are possible.

Comment: Maybe you could make one as an answer, chain width and hub width should be findable with some digging and there is some data on cog pitch here http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

Comment: After just reading the title of your question, I had Sheldon Brown's link all ready for an answer, but you've already been there, it seems. In other areas of his site, he also discusses custum combinations. See: [Shimano Cassettes and Freehub](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7.html#spacing).

Comment: I feel this would be an enormous table, and not really a lot of use.  What is the underlying question you're trying to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The simple table you are looking for isn't really possible to compile. There are differences in what Shimano, SRAM and Campagnolo do, and road and MTB drivetrains have increasingly diverged. You can see that on [this page](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/) that has a table of sprocket pitches (distance between sprocket centers) and the Sheldon Brown table [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-spacing.html). 12 speed systems have diverged even more.

There is not really a one-to-one relationship between hub width and number of speeds. Older 5 and six speed hubs were either 120 or 126mm wide. Modern road bikes went to 130mm (on rim brake bikes) to accommodate up to 11 speeds, wider widths are driven by disc brakes and rear through-axles, not increasing numbers of sprockets in the cassette. Same kind of deal for mountain bikes, but with wider widths.

[This page](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1220/1-bicycle-chains-compatibility/) gives chain widths for 7 through 12 speeds, it's generally correct although I'm a bit skeptical about the actual chain width figures. I'm fairly sure there are differences between road and mountain chains.